# datatable replaces variable with data from outside its scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using datatables.net to show some file attachments, now I want to add a description and a edit link to my action in a controller, but its acting really wierd.

I have this code

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
        var id = oObj.aData[0];
        var uploaded = oObj.aData[1];
        var dosseirId = oObj.aData[2];
        var contentLenght = oObj.aData[3];
        var filename = oObj.aData[4];
        var description = oObj.aData[5];
        var contentType = oObj.aData[6];

        var retVal = '<div>' + '<div>' + '<a href="' + GetAbsolutePath('Attachment/Download?id=' + id) + '">' + filename + '</a>' + '<a href="Delete" onclick="javascript:systematic_HTMLEditor.handleDelete(' + id + '); return false;"><img src="' + GetAbsolutePath('Content/remove-upload.png') + '" /> </a>' + '</div>' + '</div>';

        return retVal;
    },
    "aTargets": [0],
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [1]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [2]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [3]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [4]
},

{
    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
        var id = oObj.aData[0];
        var uploaded = oObj.aData[1];
        var dosseirId = oObj.aData[2];
        var contentLenght = oObj.aData[3];
        var filename = oObj.aData[4];
        var description = oObj.aData[5];
        var contentType = oObj.aData[6];

        var retVal = id;

        return retVal;
    },
    "aTargets": [6],
    "bSortable": true
}
```

But this gives me this result

```
Attachment Description Editlink

"attachment3.pdf" "i dag" "attachment3.pdf"
```

So the 3 column should be the ID of the attachment, but is translated to the result from aTargets[0] which is the attachment3.pdf, I then tried renaming a lot of variables without any result AND if I change so I dont print id, but `contentType` or `contentLength` then there is no issue and the correct data is shown. I need to post the ID to create an edit link

This is `oObj.aDatas` content in first part

```
aData: Array[7]
0: 21
1: "12-10-2011 08:06:00"
2: 1
3: 81695
4: "attachment3.pdf"
5: "i dag"
6: "application/pdf"
length: 7
```

Here, in the second part, and how ID suddenly gets this value from previous code I really don't get.

```
    aData: Array[7]
0: "<div><div><a href="/Attachment/Download?id=21">attachment3.pdf</a><a href="Delete" onclick="javascript:systematic_HTMLEditor.handleDelete(21); return false;"><img src="/Content/remove-upload.png" /> </a></div></div>"
1: "12-10-2011 08:06:00"
2: "1"
3: "81695"
4: "attachment3.pdf"
5: "i dag"
6: "application/pdf"
length: 7
```

Comment: Could you try to console.log the oObj and paste the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening here is fnRender actually changes the value in `aData.oObj`. What you need is to set `bUseRendered: false`

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
        var id = oObj.aData[0];
        var uploaded = oObj.aData[1];
        var dosseirId = oObj.aData[2];
        var contentLenght = oObj.aData[3];
        var filename = oObj.aData[4];
        var description = oObj.aData[5];
        var contentType = oObj.aData[6];

        var retVal = '<div>' + '<div>' + '<a href="' + GetAbsolutePath('Attachment/Download?id=' + id) + '">' + filename + '</a>' + '<a href="Delete" onclick="javascript:systematic_HTMLEditor.handleDelete(' + id + '); return false;"><img src="' + GetAbsolutePath('Content/remove-upload.png') + '" /> </a>' + '</div>' + '</div>';

        return retVal;
    },
    "bUseRendered": false,
    "aTargets": [0],
    "bSortable": true
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [1]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [2]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [3]
}, {
    "bVisible": false,
    "aTargets": [4]
},

{
    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
        var id = oObj.aData[0];
        var uploaded = oObj.aData[1];
        var dosseirId = oObj.aData[2];
        var contentLenght = oObj.aData[3];
        var filename = oObj.aData[4];
        var description = oObj.aData[5];
        var contentType = oObj.aData[6];

        var retVal = id;

        return retVal;
    },
    "aTargets": [6],
    "bSortable": true
}
```

Comment: Cool that solved the issue, seems like a strange "feature" though

Comment: Some of these 'issues' can be solved by using mDataProp and object literals with key names, instead of arrays with indexes. The problem stems from the difference between the full data set being returned, and the data being rendered out to the table. Each will have its own set of indexes which do not line up once some columns become hidden. It's a great feature (you might want to manipulate based on either original or modified data set)!